# setWriteTimestampToKafka in Flink 1.14 +

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am migrating from Flink **1.10.2** to Flink **1.14.5** and I can't find how to write timestamps to Kafka sink. Before I had

```
producer.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true)
```

with Flink 14 in my output I have the timestamps equals to ts from source, but with older version or when I'm using Table API (Flink 14) I have current timestamp for Kafka records. In all the cases I'm using Event Time.

**My source:**

```
KafkaSource.builder()
          .setTopics("topic_source")
          .setBootstrapServers("bootstrap.servers")
          .setGroupId("group.id")
          .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST))
          .setProperty("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "true")
          .setValueOnlyDeserializer(schema)
          .build()
```

**My sink:**

```
KafkaSink.builder()
        .setBootstrapServers("bootstrap.servers")
        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
            .setTopicSelector(topicSelector)
            .setValueSerializationSchema(schema)
            .build()
        )
        .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .setKafkaProducerConfig(props)
        .build()
```

**Watermarks:**

```
val wmStrategy: WatermarkStrategy[AnritsuA] = WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
val stream = env.fromSource(kafka_source, wmStrategy, jobArgs("topic_source"))
```

Can someone point me why it's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataStream API you can set the [KafkaRecordSerializationSchema](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.java) and create a `KafkaRecord` as you see fit.

By default and with the [KafkaRecordSerializationSchemaBuilder](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaRecordSerializationSchemaBuilder.java), the event timestamp of the record is used (e.g. the timestamp of the input record). That's usually the desired timestamp when you enrich events.

Afaik if you just set `null`, Kafka will attach the current timestamp on receiving the record. If that's the behavior of Table API, it's probably rather a bug than a feature (but seems to work for you).

Alternatively, if you don't need timestamps at all during your processing, you could also assign timestamps at the source. Or simply switch to processing time. The written timestamps are then the timestamps assigned at the source by default.

Comment: I added my code parts in the main topic. I understand that It's the standard behavior of event time processing. The thing I don't understand is why before It wasn't the same behavior with event time processing as well.  When I used Table API I didn't set up watermarks so probably It can explain why I had processing time in sink topic timestamps

Comment: I don't quite get "The thing I don't understand is why before It wasn't the same behavior with event time processing as well.". Can you try to implement your own SerializationSchema (just look at the builder for how it's done by default and set the timestamp to null).

Comment: I think I got you now. I'd consider the old behavior a bug tbh (or at least inconsistent behavior).